# Octave invalid use of script in index expression

Tags: statistics, octave

I try to use the **fitgmdist.m** to fit a gaussian mixture model. However, when it call the constructor of class **gmdistribution**.I got the error messgae as below:

**error: invalid use of script /home/ubuntu/UAVProject_DataStructure/gmdistribution.m in index expression
error: called from:
error:   /home/ubuntu/UAVProject_DataStructure/fitgmdist.m at line 505, column 7
error:   /home/ubuntu/UAVProject_DataStructure/computeGMM.m at line 78, column 10
error:   /home/ubuntu/UAVProject_DataStructure/ImageProcessing.m at line 18, column 13**

I put the 2 files: **fitgmdist.m** and **gmdistribution.m** in the current directory.

And I also change gmdistribution.m name to avoid having the same name of the octave library's file, but it doesn't work. Can someone help? Thanks.

Here is calling the constructor code:

`obj = gmdistribution (best_params.mu, best_params.Sigma, best_params.p');`

Here is the constructor Code:

```
 ########################################
  ## Constructor
  function obj = gmdistribution (mu,sigma,p = [],extra = [])
    obj.DistributionName = "gaussian mixture distribution";
    obj.mu = mu;
    obj.Sigma = sigma;
    obj.NumComponents = rows (mu);
    obj.NumVariables = columns (mu);
    if (isempty (p))
      obj.ComponentProportion = ones (1,obj.NumComponents) / obj.NumComponents;
    else
      if any (p < 0)
        error ("gmmdistribution: component weights must be non-negative");
      endif
      s = sum(p);
      if (s == 0)
        error ("gmmdistribution: component weights must not be all zero");
      elseif (s != 1)
        p = p / s;
      endif
      obj.ComponentProportion = p(:)';
    endif
    if (length (size (sigma)) == 3)
      obj.SharedCovariance = false;
    else
      obj.SharedCovariance = true;
    endif
    if (rows (sigma) == 1 && columns (mu) > 1)
      obj.DiagonalCovariance = true;
      obj.CovarianceType = 'diagonal';
    else
      obj.DiagonalCovariance = false;       ## full
      obj.CovarianceType = 'full';
    endif

    if (!isempty (extra))
      obj.AIC                   = extra.AIC;
      obj.BIC                   = extra.BIC;
      obj.Converged             = extra.Converged;
      obj.NegativeLogLikelihood = extra.NegativeLogLikelihood;
      obj.NlogL                 = extra.NegativeLogLikelihood;
      obj.NumIterations         = extra.NumIterations;
      obj.RegularizationValue   = extra.RegularizationValue;
    endif
  endfunction
```

Comment: I think you should create a MCVE (strip down your code as far as possible and make sure that someone else can run your code (completeness))

Comment: It sounds like your class isn't properly defined, so octave doesn't detect it's a class definition and tries to treat it as a simple script (and then it complains that you're trying to call it with arguments). Do you have appropriate `classdef` and `methods` in place?